# Visual Studio Compiler Default for /O

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization

Does VS2010/12's compiler use a default optimization level when none of /Od,/O1,/O2,/Ox is provided in a C++ compilation command line?

I'm currently using /Od since I witnessed some optimization related bugs when using the other levels. However, this leads to /GS being disabled - which is unwanted.

When I clear the box for the "Project Properties->C/C++->Optimization->Optimization" option, I see the command line indeed doesn't contain any option. But I don't know if this just means the compiler uses some default optimization level.

Comment: just fyi: when a bug in C++ only manifests in debug mode, it's most likely because you wrote code which has undefined behavior. Some frequent examples for this are buffer overruns, uninitalized variables and race conditions in multi-threading. You should really try to fix these bugs so that the code runs on any optimization level.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. Unfortunately Microsoft also has bugs, and some optimization combinations have been confirmed at the time to generate incorrect code in some cases.

Comment: @Danra: True, but about a million times as rare as bugs in your code. When I see a tiger in the street, it could have walked here from Africa, but I'm still going to suspect it escaped from the local zoo or circus.

Comment: Maybe about a dozen times as rare ;)

Comment: @Danra: can you describe some of those bugs?

Comment: It was quite a while ago. I recall it was two optimizations which collide with each other, but don't have the time to look it up right now. In here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/08/10/10338661.aspx there's a list of compiler back-end bugs fixed for the VS2012 compiler, including for example "C++ compiler generates wrong code with optimization flag /O2". In any case, let's stop this thread here, as it's completely irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No optimization seems to be the default - see output from "cl /?" below:

```
                          -OPTIMIZATION-

  /O1 minimize space                      /O2 maximize speed
  /Ob<n> inline expansion (default n=0)   /Od disable optimizations (default)
  /Og enable global optimization          /Oi[-] enable intrinsic functions
  /Os favor code space                    /Ot favor code speed
  /Ox maximum optimizations               /Oy[-] enable frame pointer omission
```

Comment: This indeed seems to be the behavior - Still getting the /GS disabled warnings after removing the /Od flag.

Comment: @Danra: what are these "/GS disabled" warnings?  And what is the compiler command line being used?

Comment: warning C4748. Caused by /GS enabled while optimization is disabled (/Od).